# How to find the perturbation of $x^2 − 1 = \epsilon x$?

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion

Is there a function in Mathematica that can be used to find the perturbation solution of an equation like $x^2 − 1 = \epsilon \,x$, $x − 2 = \epsilon \cosh(x)$ or $x^2 − 1 = \epsilon\, e^x$?

Comment: What would you expect the output to look like?

Comment: @bills, Something like $x=a_0+a_1\epsilon +a_2\epsilon^{2}+...$

Comment: There's a [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SolvingEquationsInvolvingPowerSeries.html) about this exact thing.

Answer (score 13):

Decide up to which power you would like to expand:

```
pow = 4;
```

Let's do one of the equations you mentioned as an example (bring all terms to one side and save as a single expression, `eq` in this case):

```
eq = x - 2 - e Cosh[x];
```

Write an ansatz for the `x` solution with unknown coefficients:

```
ansatz = Sum[a[i] e^i, {i, 0, pow}];
```

Substitute the ansatz into your expression and do a series expansion:

```
expand = Series[eq /. x -> ansatz, {e, 0, pow}];
```

Solve the constraints of overall factors vanishing:

```
vars = Table[a[i], {i, 0, pow}];
sols = Solve[expand == 0, vars][[1]] // Simplify // Quiet;
```

Finally, insert the solution into your ansatz to obtain the result:

```
res = ansatz /. sols
```

> `2 + e Cosh[2] + e^2 Cosh[2] Sqrt[-1 + Cosh[2]^2] + 
>    1/3 e^4 Cosh[2] Sqrt[-1 + Cosh[2]^2] (-3 + 8 Cosh[2]^2) + 
>    e^3 (-Cosh[2] + (3 Cosh[2]^3)/2)`

Don't forget to test numerically, whether your result is actually correct at the end:

```
enum = 10^-10;
xnum = x /.FindRoot[(eq /. e -> enum) == 0, {x, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 60];
(res /. e -> enum) - xnum
```

> `-3.627605747396*10^-47`

This shows that expanding to fourth order with an `e= 10^-10` indeed consistently matches the result up to about `10^-50` accuracy, so the expansion was correct. Rinse and repeat for the other examples.

PS: In cases where your equation admits several solutions you might have to be a little bit more careful, but the principle still stays the same.

Answer (score 6):

For these simple examples you could use `InverseSeries`. For example:

```
InverseSeries[Series[(x^2 - 1)/x, {x, 1, 10}], e]
InverseSeries[Series[(x - 2)/Cosh[x], {x, 2, 10}], e]
InverseSeries[Series[(x^2 - 1)/E^x, {x, 1, 10}], e]
```

You need to solve for `e`, and then do a series around the value of `x` when `e` is zero.

Answer (score 3):

The new in M12 function [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) can be used to find these perturbation expansions:

```
AsymptoticSolve[x^2 - 1 == ϵ x, {x, 1}, {ϵ, 0, 7}]
```

> {{x -> 1 + ϵ/2 + ϵ^2/8 - ϵ^4/128 + ϵ^6/
>       1024}}

```
AsymptoticSolve[x - 2 == ϵ Cosh[x], {x, 2}, {ϵ, 0, 7}]
```

> {{x -> 2 + ϵ Cosh[2] + ϵ^2 Cosh[2] Sinh[2] + 
>       1/2 ϵ^3 (Cosh[2]^3 + 2 Cosh[2] Sinh[2]^2) + 
>       1/3 ϵ^4 (5 Cosh[2]^3 Sinh[2] + 3 Cosh[2] Sinh[2]^3) + 
>       1/24 ϵ^5 (13 Cosh[2]^5 + 88 Cosh[2]^3 Sinh[2]^2 + 
>          24 Cosh[2] Sinh[2]^4) + 
>       1/15 ϵ^6 (47 Cosh[2]^5 Sinh[2] + 100 Cosh[2]^3 Sinh[2]^3 + 
>          15 Cosh[2] Sinh[2]^5) + 
>       1/720 ϵ^7 (541 Cosh[2]^7 + 7746 Cosh[2]^5 Sinh[2]^2 + 
>          7800 Cosh[2]^3 Sinh[2]^4 + 720 Cosh[2] Sinh[2]^6)}}

```
AsymptoticSolve[x^2 - 1 == ϵ Exp[x], {x, 1}, {ϵ, 0, 7}]
AsymptoticSolve[x^2 - 1 == ϵ Exp[x], {x, -1}, {ϵ, 0, 7}]
```

> {{x -> 1 + (E ϵ)/2 + (E^2 ϵ^2)/8 + (E^3 ϵ^3)/16 + (
>       13 E^4 ϵ^4)/384 + (E^5 ϵ^5)/48 + (69 E^6 ϵ^6)/
>       5120 + (841 E^7 ϵ^7)/92160}}
>
> {{x -> -1 - ϵ/(2 E) + (3 ϵ^2)/(8 E^2) - (7 ϵ^3)/(
>       16 E^3) + (235 ϵ^4)/(384 E^4) - (121 ϵ^5)/(128 E^5) + (
>       7959 ϵ^6)/(5120 E^6) - (245953 ϵ^7)/(92160 E^7)}}

Answer (score 2):

According to standard perturbation theory for static Hamiltonians of this type, the ground state of the system may be approximated by:

\begin{align}
    |0\rangle_V &= 
    |0\rangle_H - \epsilon  \sum_{\alpha\neq 0} \frac{U_{\alpha 0}}{\alpha} |\alpha\rangle_H
    \\ \notag 
    &\simeq N^{-\frac12} \left ( |0\rangle_H + \beta_1
    |1\rangle_H + \beta_2 |2\rangle_H \right)\,,
    \end{align}
    where $N=1+\beta_1^2+\beta_2^2$, 
    $\beta_k = -\epsilon U_{\alpha 0}/\alpha$ and $U_{\alpha 0}={}_H\langle
\alpha|U| 0 \rangle_H$, $\alpha=1,2$.

Hope this helps to formulate your problem.